# Reference resources from a test-jat artifact

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have two artifact:

- **artifact-A**: contains resources in src/test/resources/

> ```
> <plugins>
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2</version>
>     <executions>
>       <execution>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>test-jar</goal>
>         </goals>
>       </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> </plugins>
> ```

- **artifact B**: uses resources from artifact A

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.xxxx.yyy</groupId>
>   <artifactId>artifact-A</artifactId>
>   <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <type>test-jar</type>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

The problem is that the resources are never extracted in the project artifact-B.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a dependency like this the used jar will never be extracted cause it will be put on the classpath during compilation etc. This means to access the resources from artifact-A you need to access them via the classpath.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is there a way to extract resources with a specific plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

In artifact-B, I used the maven-dependency-plugin to extract resources from the test-jar

> ```
> <plugin> 
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
>             <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> 
>             <version>2.4</version> 
>             <executions> 
>                 <execution> 
>                     <id>resource-dependencies</id> 
>                     <phase>process-test-resources</phase> 
>                     <goals> 
>                         <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal> 
>                     </goals> 
>                     <configuration> 
>                         <includeArtifactIds>artifact-A</includeArtifactIds> 
>                         <includes>**/db-test/*</includes>  
>                         <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory> 
>                     </configuration> 
>                 </execution> 
>             </executions> 
>         </plugin>
> ```